# Using flair in secure enviroments (HTTPS)

Tags: feature-request, flair

It'd be nice if the different flair options could be hosted on HTTPS as well as HTTP, so that they could be used in — for example — HTTPS-secured intranet sites.

Comment: Oh, god. Flair on an intranet site?! You're taking SO too seriously.

Comment: I can see a status-declined in your immediate future...

Comment: Haha, quite possibly. It's more of a challenge to my coworkers.

Comment: I have my flair on my internal Sharepoint page.  What else do you put there?

Comment: Congrats on two and a half years -- a quarter decade! -- without being declined! CC @MarcGravell

Answer (score 3):

This is possible now that StackExchange has basic SSL support, just change the protocol to `https`.

[se-flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stackexchange-site-flair) also supports HTTPS if you use the PNG image version.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little proxy script a https server that retrieves the flair image (over http)

In php the script would look something like this:

```
<?php
$image = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/19165.png');
foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
    header($header);
}
echo $image;
exit();
```

Just replace 19165 with your StackOverflow id.